# ADODB ->numRows() or COUNT(*) $ADODB_COUNTRECS

Tags: mysql, adodb, adodb-php

Optimization question. There is an $ADODB_COUNTRECS parameter that makes requests immediately counting the number of lines. However, he constantly makes this request, and it is often unnecessary. I'm trying to turn off $ADODB_COUNTRECS and also do a separate COUNT(*) query.

**Is it more effective or not? **

And secondly, if I turn off $ADODB_COUNTRECS, then in some cases it does not allow me to make a new request to the database until the output of the previous request cycle is completed. In this case, I use ->getArray() , then the array is multidimensional.

**So which method is ultimately better? leave the ->numRows() or make a separate request COUNT(*) and turn off $ADODB_COUNTRECS**

the best way to reduce load and increase site speed

IN additional microtime

*Execution time with numRows(): 0.2532958984375 seconds
Execution time without numRows(): 0.00015091896057129 seconds*

Comment: How often do they change?  If its not that often, why not just store the counted value into a table, and then have an event run every hour to recount and update that value, then you can just get that number instead of having to do all the work.  If its getting constant updates then this wouldn't work, but the idea is, the heavy lifting is done outside of the request so that it already has the info it needs to speed along.

Comment: Also .. curious .. what is the need of counting the records? Are you trying to get the highest value to insert the next one or something?  Because there are built in systems for that.

Comment: Of note you can add the EXPLAIN command to a mysql statement to tell it to give more information including if i recall execution time.  Which of note, can also be tracked without that using MySQL Workbench among other benefits it offers.

Comment: Or you can just calculate the elapsedtime of your php script with a diff of microtime

Comment: You could also include an insert statement with each statement that is executed to create a log in another table that way you can not only get the current results, you can have historical data to compare against as you find refinements.